# JS Object value dependant upon other object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, var

I'm making a pokemon battle in Javascript. I have made objects for Pokemon and moves. ie

```js
var party1 = prompt("Pick BULBASAUR, SQUIRTLE, CHARMANDER, or PIKACHU")
confirm("You encountered a wild pokemon!")
var inPokemon = null /*Pokemon{party1}; Here i want party1 to be user input selecting a pokemon, so i can call Pokemon.party1 //which could equal "PIKACHU"//*/
var encounter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var Pokemon = {
  Charmander: {
    name: "Charmander",
    moves: [moves.EMBER, moves.SCRATCH, moves.GROWL],
    stats: [5, 20, 5, "FIRE"]
  },
  Pikachu: {
    name: "Pikachu",
    moves: [moves.SPARK, moves.SCRATCH, moves.SAND_ATTACK],
    stats: [5, 25, 6, "ELECTRIC"]
  },
  Bulbasaur: {
    name: "Bulbasaur",
    moves: [moves.BULLET_SEED, moves.POUND, moves.SAND_ATTACK],
    stats: [5, 22, 3, "GRASS"]
  },
  Squirtle: {
    name: "Squirtle",
    moves: [moves.BUBBLE, moves.POUND, moves.GROWL],
    stats: [5, 18, 7, "WATER"]
  }
}
var moves = {
  BUBBLE: {
    name: "BUBBLE",
    stats: [12, "WATER"],
    effect: null
  },
  POUND: {
    name: "POUND",
    stats: [10, "NORMAL"],
    effect: null
  },
  GROWL: {
    name: "GROWL",
    stats: [0, "NORMAL", /*here I want it to be something like (Pokemon.party1.stats[2]*(.2) //reduced by 20%// */ ]
  },
}
```

My two issues are similar and are mentioned in the code above, I want an attribute of an object to change due to outside variables or attributes of another object. And I dont know how to do that, obviously. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your snipper has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(<your array>, "<the index>", {
    get() {
        return <enter relative value here>;
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
Object.defineProperty(array, "3", {
  get() {
    return array[0] * array[1];
  }
});
console.log(array[3]);//1*2=2
array[0] = 7;
console.log(array[3]);//7*2=14
array[1] = 3;
console.log(array[3]);//7*3=21
```